# Problems with zsh, flutter and android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, zsh

I'm completely lost at this point. I turned on machine today and android studio couldn't recognize the device but vs code could, after spending hours finding solution. I reinstalled android studio and reset everything and now android studio recognizes the device but after clicking on run I see `Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components.`
but running flutter doctor shows this

```
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ ANDROID_HOME =
      /home/udaykhalsa/Android/Sdk:/home/udaykhalsa/Android/Sdk:/home/udaykhalsa
      /Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/udaykhalsa/Programming-EnvironmentFiles/
      flutter/bin:/home/udaykhalsa/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/
      local/sbin:/opt/android-sdk/tools:/opt/android-sdk/tools/bin:/var/lib/flat
      pak/exports/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendo
      r_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin
      but Android SDK not found at this location.
```

.zshrc

```
export ZSH="/home/udaykhalsa/.oh-my-zsh"
export PATH="/home/udaykhalsa/Programming-EnvironmentFiles/flutter/bin":$PATH
export PATH="/home/udaykhalsa/Android/Sdk/platform-tools":$PATH
export PATH="/home/udaykhalsa/Android/Sdk":$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/udaykhalsa/Android/Sdk":$PATH
```

I'm not daring to make any changes to zshrc as I did a while back all the commands were not found. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perform below, and did you observe the 'adb' file?

```
$ ls $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb
```

Am using macOS, my sdk is found inside 'Library' folder unlike yours. Should NOT be an issue if Android Studio is already working for you.

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/someuser/Library/Android/sdk":$PATH
```

To see connected devices, issue either commands:

```
$ adb devices
$ flutter devices
```

Comment: I tried everything and finally found this solution in a github thread and everything's fine now. Used ```flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>```.

Comment: Great! Glad that you found the solution to your issue.